# Bison: Shift/Reduce Conflict resolution when dealing with optional rules

Tags: bison, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

On the grammar of a .y (yacc -- bison) file I've defined the following rules:

> C : E | D | F | A
>
> A : B | B '[' C ']' ;

(this is something like B with optional [C])
when I compile the .y file in the appropriate way using a proper lexer file I get the following shift\reduce conflict:

> State 48
> 74        A: B .
> 75         | B . '[' C ']'
> '[' shift, and go to state 91
> '[' [reduce using rule 74 (A)]
> $default  reduce using rule 74 (A)

My problem is the following if it has predecessor '[' I want it to shift and not reduce. The problem is I cannot find the solution to this error, while searching for hours on the documentation.
How can I fix this (please be code-specific).

Comment: You have not supplied enough information to reproduce your error. When I create a bison file from your example I find no problems.  Show more code that reproduces your error please.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is some context in which an `A` might be followed by a `[`. Without seeing more of the grammar, it is impossible to be more precise.

However, it is worth noting that bison/yacc will do exactly what you want: resolve the conflict in favour of the shift. So aside from the warning, everything should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to expand the A rule, you get two possible states

State 1:

```
A -> B
```

State 2:

```
A -> B
A -> BC
```

All possible states for A are the following

```
A -> B (State 1)
A -> B (State 2)
A -> BC
```

Bison can not determine if you are in the State 1 or 2 for B input.

You can replace the A rule by (assuming B and C are tokens):

```
A: B | B C
```